# Read data from serial port using ReadFile function in C99

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, c99

I need send a data using serial port and I have a little problem. When I receive a data using ReadFile function, any data are get as signed char not unsigned.

My data send in HEX

```
0 - 7
1 - 8f
2 - 54
3 - 59
4 - 50
5 - 1
6 - 6b
7 - ff
```

Data received by Terminal to check any bit is send correct
[image: Data received by Terminal v 1.9]

Data received by program using ReadFile

```
0 - 7
1 - f
2 - 54
3 - 59
4 - 50
5 - 1
6 - 6b
7 - 7f
```

File handler

```
HANDLE hComm;
hComm = CreateFile(
    p_port, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL
);
```

Function to read data from serial port

```
void
getMessage(HANDLE hComm, unsigned char * dataStorage, int storageSize)
{
    DWORD dNoBytesToRead;
    ReadFile(hComm, dataStorage, storageSize, &dNoBytesToRead, NULL);
}
```

EDIT: This is not problem with WinApi. https://github.com/Draqun/WinApiSerialPortExample - example project show that.

Comment: Nothing to do with ReadFile, it doesn't behave like that.  It'll be the port configuration - it's probably set to 7 bits, or something like that.  I'm not familiar with the API, but perhaps SetCommState?

Comment: `ReadFile` doesn't know or care about data types. It simply reads a stream of octets. It's up to the application to interpret those bytes. This doesn't look like a signed/unsigned type mismatch either. It looks like the MSB is stripped off (see bytes 1 and 7). Sounds more like a configuration problem of the serial port, but since I know nothing about serial ports I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Yea, I create simple app to check it and there all work fine. It's not problem with WinAPi.

Comment: Calling SetCommState() to configure the serial port to match the device settings is never really optional.  You would have to use the MODE command before you start your program, just about nobody does that.

Comment: The code you've posted in your question is identical to the code in the sample project that you say works perfectly.  Please clarify what your problem is, and post a [mcve].